# How to print a statement one time in a loop

Tags: python

I have the following code :

```
  for nodeid,nodeip in zip(node['id'], node['ip']):
          nodeurl = url.format(nodeid, nodeip)
          x = requests.get(nodeurl,headers=headers , auth=('admin', '0p3nNM$2015'))
          parsed = json.loads(x.content)
          ##print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
          for i in parsed["service"]:
              #print i["serviceType"]["name"]

              if i["serviceType"]["name"]=="SSH":
                 print "OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP: " ## How to print it just ONCE
                 print nodeip
                 slack.chat.post_message(slack_channel,">>>"+nodeip,username='OPENNMS_FRA_BOT')
              else:
                 print "No IP found with SSH running"
```

So the thing is, this code works fine. **All** I want now is just to have the following type of output if a IP is found with the mentioned condition:

```
OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP:
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
.
.
.
so on
```

But the above code prints

```
OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP:
10.0.0.1
OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP:
10.0.0.2
OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP:
10.0.0.3
.
.
.
so on
```

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: Just add another `if` clause to check whether the current IP is the first one to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply hold a stateful variable called `first`. Once you print the line, toggle `first` to `False` so it doesn't execute again.

```
first = True
for nodeid,nodeip in zip(node['id'], node['ip']):
      nodeurl = url.format(nodeid, nodeip)
      x = requests.get(nodeurl,headers=headers , auth=('admin', '0p3nNM$2015'))
      parsed = json.loads(x.content)
      ##print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
      for i in parsed["service"]:
          #print i["serviceType"]["name"]

          if i["serviceType"]["name"]=="SSH":
             if first:
                 print "OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP: "
                 first = False
             print nodeip
             slack.chat.post_message(slack_channel,">>>"+nodeip,username='OPENNMS_FRA_BOT')
          else:
             print "No IP found with SSH running"
```

This isn't the prettiest way of doing it, but it will do the behavior you want. One nice thing, though, is that it adds very little memory/complexity to the program. Another way would be to hold every result in a list and print it at the end - but that would require holding a reference to every result until the very end. If your program is generating a lot of results, that can take up a lot of memory. This only holds a boolean...

Comment: I like this , also i can hold a second variable , just like end and just add that after slack.chat.post_message(slack_channel,">>>"+nodeip,username='OPENNMS_FRA_BOT') , to print "Clean the above nodes"

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it! "There arealways  multiple ways of doing one thing" - anonymous

Answer (score 1):

Store your data in a list:

```
 node_list = []
 ...
         for i in parsed["service"]:
              if i["serviceType"]["name"]=="SSH":
                 node_list.append(nodeip)
 ...
 print "OpenNMS BOT Found the following IP: "
 for item in node_list:
     print item
```